# Process stucked at recvfrom syscall

Tags: linux, socket, lsof, strace

A process is stucked at `recvfrom` syscall.

```
> sudo strace -p 4146278
strace:  Process 4146278 attached
recvfrom(9 ...
```

I looked up under /proc/4146278/fd.
fd 9 seems to be a socket.

```
> sudo ls -al /proc/4146278/fd/9
/proc/4146278/fd/9 -> 'socket:[3341923555]'
```

However I could not find anything related to that socket. I tried

```
lsof -i -a -p 4146278
```

and

```
lsof -i | grep 3341923555
```

Both show nothing.

How can I find out what is causing the stuck?

Comment: can you se the given socket using `ss -p` ?

Comment: @etosan unfortunately not.

Comment: Are you running `ss -p` as root? Unless you are running `ss` as `su` you won't see other processes. Also what kind of socket is `fd/9` ? if it's unix you need to add `-x` if its udp `-u` and if its tcp `-t`. All this you could get by reading ss's man page.

Comment: Yes I was running `ss -p` as root. It was Linux. Unfortunately, the same issue has not occurred since I posted this question. I will try your advice next time.